# The left and right eigenvectors of non-negative matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Problem: Let $A$ be a non-negative matrix. Show that if $A$ has positive right and left eigenvectors there exists a positive matrix $B$ such that $AB = BA$.

Denote the positive right eigenvector be $v$ and the positive left eigenvectors be $u$, then $Av=\lambda_i v$ and $u^TA = \lambda_j u^T$, construct $B$ as $B=vu^T$, then $AB=Avu^T=\lambda_i vu^T$ and $BA=vu^TA=\lambda_jvu^T$. If $\lambda_i=\lambda_j$, then $AB=BA$, the proof is finished. But I do not know how to prove that $\lambda_i=\lambda_j$ because A may not be regular. Could you please give me some ideas?

Comment: Hint: $v_i^T A v_i = \lambda_i$ is true whether or not $\lambda_i = 0$.

Comment: slightly different, use a bilinear form:  $\mathbf u^T \mathbf v \gt 0$ by positivity of the eigenvectors, but $ \mathbf u^T A \mathbf v =\big(\mathbf u^T A\big) \mathbf v=\mathbf u^T \big(A \mathbf v\big)\implies \lambda_i = \lambda_j$